# -prefix-free jquery plugin IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9, prefixfree

I'm having issues using prefixfree, the jquery plugin does not seem to work in internet explorer 9.
(maybe it's just some screwed up setting in my browser, I don't know, but prefixfree itself does the job all right: the initial rotate(20deg) is prefixed)

I have set up a jsbin example showing what I mean: http://jsbin.com/ocipel/2/edit

I tested this in chrome and firefox, which work as expected. Any help is greatly appreciated.
(oh and it seems prefixfree does not exist as a tag, so I had to split it up into "prefix" and "free", sorry for that)

Comment: i doubt anyone's looking for questions for "prefix-free", "prefix", or "free" so since you have internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9 and jquery as tags you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your prefix-free plugin only runs at pageload. Since the prefix-free plugin parses each stylesheet in your document on pageload, the square is rotated 20deg.
After pageload you give the css property `transform` another value with javascript, but the prefix-free plugin does not know that. So you should 're-run' the prefix-free plugin after each interval.

EDIT: it seems I do not need the plugin for jQuery 1.8.0+, which auto-prefixed the css properties already, so thanks for making me search again. (anyways I still don't know why it did not work, but it does not have to now)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think that is the case. What the plugin does is override the default jQuery css properties with the prefixed one by doing this `$.cssProps[camelCased] = PrefixCamelCased;` which means every call to the css property `transform` should be replaced by `-ms-transform` or the webkit and moz equivalents.

And what's more, it works in chrome and firefox. (I did not write this plugin myself, I got it from the official prefixfree website)

Comment: Chrome and firefox work without prefixes, that's why your project works in these browsers.

Comment: My god, this is not serious, I did some more searching and it seems jQuery 1.8.0+ handles auto-prefixing itself. So the plugin is completely needless.